# How can I get layers data in relation to their group name?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, javascript, cc-2019

I am making a Photoshop script which gets every layer with Bevel and Emboss effect and then doing some actions. I have make this function so to get layers data...

```
function getLayersData()  
{  
    var lyrs = [];  
    var layers = 1;  
    while (true)  
    {  
        ref = new ActionReference();  
        ref.putIndex(charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), layers);  

        try  
        {  
            var d1 = executeActionGet(ref);  
            var d2 = executeActionGet(ref);  
            var d3 = executeActionGet(ref);  
            var d4 = executeActionGet(ref);  
        }  
            catch (err)  
        {  
            break;  
        };  

        var c2t = function (s){return app.charIDToTypeID(s);};  
        var s2t = function (s){return app.stringIDToTypeID(s);};  
        var lyr = {};  

        lyr.type = d1.getInteger(s2t("layerKind"));  
        lyr.name = d1.getString(c2t("Nm  "));  
        lyr.id = d1.getInteger(s2t("layerID"));  

        if (checkbox1.value == true)  
        {  
            ref.putEnumerated( c2t("Lyr "), c2t("Ordn"), c2t("Trgt") );  
            if (d1.hasKey(s2t('layerEffects')))  
            {  
                d1 = d1.getObjectValue(s2t('layerEffects'));  
                lyr.scale = d1.getUnitDoubleValue(s2t('scale'));  

                if (d1.hasKey(s2t('bevelEmboss')))  
                {  
                    d1 = d1.getObjectValue(s2t('bevelEmboss'));  
                        lyr.enabled = d1.getBoolean(s2t('enabled'));  
                        lyr.present = d1.getBoolean(s2t('present'));  
                        lyr.showInDialog = d1.getBoolean(s2t('showInDialog'));  
                        lyr.highlightMode = typeIDToStringID(d1.getEnumerationValue(s2t('highlightMode')));  
                    d2 = d1.getObjectValue(s2t('highlightColor'));  
                        lyr.red_hlc = d2.getDouble(s2t('red'));  
                        lyr.grn_hlc = d2.getDouble(s2t('green'));  
                        lyr.blue_hlc = d2.getDouble(s2t('blue'));  
                        lyr.highlightOpacity = d1.getUnitDoubleValue(s2t('highlightOpacity'));  
                        lyr.shadowMode = typeIDToStringID(d1.getEnumerationValue(s2t('shadowMode')))  
                    d3 = d1.getObjectValue(s2t('shadowColor'));  
                        lyr.red_sdc = d3.getDouble(s2t('red'));  
                        lyr.grn_sdc = d3.getDouble(s2t('green'));  
                        lyr.blue_sdc = d3.getDouble(s2t('blue'));  
                        lyr.shadowOpacity = d1.getUnitDoubleValue(s2t('shadowOpacity'));  
                        lyr.bevelTechnique = typeIDToStringID(d1.getEnumerationValue(s2t('bevelTechnique')));  
                        lyr.bevelStyle = typeIDToStringID(d1.getEnumerationValue(s2t('bevelStyle')));  
                        lyr.useGlobalAngle = d1.getBoolean(s2t('useGlobalAngle'));  
                        lyr.localLightingAngle = d1.getUnitDoubleValue(s2t('localLightingAngle'));  
                        lyr.localLightingAltitude = d1.getUnitDoubleValue(s2t('localLightingAltitude'));  
                        lyr.strengthRatio = d1.getUnitDoubleValue(s2t('strengthRatio'));  
                        lyr.blur = d1.getUnitDoubleValue(s2t('blur'));  
                        lyr.bevelDirection = typeIDToStringID(d1.getEnumerationValue(s2t('bevelDirection')));  
                    d4 = d1.getObjectValue(c2t('TrnS'));  
                        lyr.TrnSName = d4.getString(s2t('name'));  
                        lyr.antialiasGloss = d1.getBoolean(s2t('antialiasGloss'));  
                        lyr.softness = d1.getUnitDoubleValue(s2t('softness'));  
                        lyr.useShape = d1.getBoolean(s2t('useShape'));  
                        lyr.useTexture = d1.getBoolean(s2t('useTexture'));  
                    lyrs.push(lyr);  
                };  
            };  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            lyrs.push(lyr);  
        };  
        layers++;  
    };      
    return lyrs;  
};
```

...and then this function so to list those layers into a Dropdownlist.

```
function onChangeDropdownlist1()  
{  
    dropdownlist2.removeAll();  
    var layerData = getLayersData();  
    var layerNames=[];  
    for(var a in layerData){if(layerData[a].type == dropdownlist1.selection.index){layerNames.push(layerData[a].name);};};  
    if (checkbox2.value == true){layerNames = UniqueSortedList(layerNames);};  
    for(var z in layerNames){dropdownlist2.add("item", layerNames[z]);};  
    dropdownlist2.selection = 0;  
    if (dropdownlist2.selection == null){edittext1.text = "";};  
};
```

What I am trying to do now, is to add the ability to get this list but in relation to the group name!!!
Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: you can use app.activeDocument.layerSets.getByName("GroupName")!

Comment: @DesignPhoenix and how can this apply into my code? :(

Comment: as far as I can understand your code successfully grab the layers with bevel right and you want to push the group of the layer with bevel right? if it's so than just use that above line which will find the group with specific name and then you can get child by ...layerSets.layers which will give you child layer. well I'm unclear on question though :(

Comment: @DesignPhoenix my code as it is now, "finds" every layer which have bevel and emboss effect and then gets effect's values. What I want to do is to find every layers which have bevel and emboss effect etc but into a specific group folder!!! In other words, I am looking for a way to get every layers parent group...

Comment: LOOOL it's so easy :D just use app.activeDocument.activeLayer.parent!  btw if you want to get parent of beveled layer just add lyr.parent right before 'lyrs.push(lyr)' which will help you finding your corresponding layers parent!

Comment: @DesignPhoenix I have already try this my friend... I have add this `lyr.parent = app.activeDocument.activeLayer.parent;` right before `lyrs.push(lyr)` as you also said and then, I am testing by doing this, `for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++){alert(layers[i].parent.name)};` into a `Button` `onClick` event. Except that it takes "thousand years" to list all those 300 layers, at the end, it gives only one group name for all found layers, which is not correct, since each layer has a different group!!!

Comment: you got it wrong bro XD if you want to push the groups then dont do lyrs.push(lyr); rather than that just create a new array from start like var grps = []; and then before pushing lyr you can push the parent by grps.push(lyr.parent); and then you'll have to loop only in grps; read more details on groups  by searching LayerSet in official reference :)